# Displaying a large pdf in HTML will result in incomplete chunked encoding error

Tags: pdf, coldfusion

My webpage has a list of pdf documents that the user can click and view it. Some of the pdf documents are massive and contains lots of images. When displaying the pdfs, the smaller ones has no problems. The bigger documents will only show blank page. Chrome console show the 
`ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING`.

I tried to optimize the pdf using `cfpdf action="optimize" algo="bilinear">` and `<cfpdf action="write" saveoption="linear">` but it still shows the same issue. I tried using the `cfscript` method where I stream out the pdf document. Still no success. The closest I've been is by following [Ben Nadel's tutorial](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2011-reading-in-file-data-one-line-at-a-time-using-coldfusion-s-cfloop-tag-or-java-s-linenumberreader.htm).

Based on the tutorial, I tried to display the pdf line by line.

```html
<cfset FULLPATH = "\\relative_path\doc_name.pdf">

<cfoutput query="qDocument">
    <cfloop
            index="line"
            file="#MFULLPATH#">

            <cfcontent variable="#toBinary(toBase64(line))#" type="application/pdf">
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

When i run the above code, the pdf reader is displayed on the page, but the error alert "Failed to load PDF document" come out. 
[image: Error message.]
Is there any other way to dsplay large pdf file (>100 pages) or I'm in the right track?

Comment: Have you tried writing it to a file using cfpdf, and then using cfcontent?

Comment: @Redtopia yup, i did. The document didn't even load. It just show blank page

Comment: Maybe ftp or otherwise download the generated document and see if you can analyze it. Maybe there’s a pdf validator you could use. Or see if it will open in acrobat